# Offset selectionChange Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular6, offset

I have a form which contains 1 drop-down list and 2 inputs.
I have a drop down list which contains several objects. When I select one of them, I can retrieve the whole object and I am supposed to filled the two other inputs with the value from the selected object.
However, it seems there is an offset when I do that.

For instance I have an object banana in my list. If i select it nothing will happen.

The 2 other inputs will not be filled at first. Then if I select another object such as apple, the banana values will be retrieved and so on if I select Orange, Apple's values will be retrieved.

> In my HTML file I have this :

```
      <mat-form-field>
          <mat-select placeholder="Code List" 
            (ngModel)]="contextScheme.codeListId" 
            (selectionChange)="completeInputAgencyAndVersion($event)">
              <mat-option *ngFor="let codeList of codeLists" 
                   [value]="codeList.codeListId">
          {{codeList.codeListName}}
              </mat-option>
         </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Scheme ID</mat-label>
    <input matInput required 
         [(ngModel)]="contextScheme.schemeId" [maxlength]="45"/>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Agency ID</mat-label>
    <input matInput required 
     [(ngModel)]="contextScheme.schemeAgencyId" [maxlength]="45"/>
  </mat-form-field>
```

> Basically I only display everything and in the ts file I have the
>   method completeInput :

```
  completeInputAgencyAndVersion(event: MatSelectChange) {
     this.service.getCodeList(event.value).subscribe(val => { 
       this.currCodeList = val; } );
       if (this.currCodeList) {
          this.contextScheme.schemeAgencyId = 
            this.currCodeList.agencyId.toString();
          this.contextScheme.schemeVersionId = 
           this.currCodeList.versionId.toString();
          this.contextScheme.ctxSchemeValues = 
          this.convertCodeListValuesIntoContextSchemeValues(
             this.currCodeList.codeListValues);
          this.dataSource.data = this.contextScheme.ctxSchemeValues;
 }
}
```

> My question is why is there this offset and how can I fix it ?

Thanks !

**EDIT :** Whenever I chose an object from my drop-down list, I can see that the correct request is sent and that I receive the correct piece of information, the issue dwells in Angular and how it load the information.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is related to Angular Change Detection which is not happening once you get your async data. You can notify angular check for change once response had come from server.

```
constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {
}

completeInputAgencyAndVersion(event: MatSelectChange) {
     this.service.getCodeList(event.value).subscribe(val => { 
       this.currCodeList = val; 
        if (this.currCodeList) {
          this.contextScheme.schemeAgencyId = 
            this.currCodeList.agencyId.toString();
          this.contextScheme.schemeVersionId = 
           this.currCodeList.versionId.toString();
          this.contextScheme.ctxSchemeValues = 
          this.convertCodeListValuesIntoContextSchemeValues(
             this.currCodeList.codeListValues);
          this.dataSource.data = this.contextScheme.ctxSchemeValues;
          this.cd.detectChanges();
 }
       } );

}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I tried what you said but there is no change at all.

Comment: Just check with `setTimeout`. Updated the answer.

Comment: you must put the if block inside the subscribe section. updated the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, it has nothing to do with the problem. I tried and the same thing happened, I can see on the developer console that I retrieve the right information, but it is not displayed. I presume it has something to do with the MatSelectChange I am using

Comment: First put the content inside response block, second use the ChangeDetection code or setTimeout option. This should solve your issue.

Comment: Actually it does not. Maybe someone else might propose something else.

Comment: It would be easier to fix if can create the stackblitz demo.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183254/discussion-between-sox-and-sunil-singh).